# Why are the FD6288T&Q gate driver logic inputs for high side switching connected to VCC?

Tags: mosfet-driver, motor-controller, gate-driving

I came across a datasheet for the [FD6288T&Q MOSFET gate driver](https://static.qingshow.net/fortiortech/file/1597746029372.pdf), which I would like to use in an ESC design. When I was incorporating it into the schematic for my ESC, I noticed that in the illustration of a typical connection in the datasheet, VCC is connected directly to the high-side switching logic inputs (HIN1, HIN2, HIN3).

[image: Image from datasheet showing external connections where the issue described applies.]

(Image above is from linked datasheet showing the external connections where the issue described applies.)

This is problematic because the gate driver says the GPIO logic pins can operate with 3.3V, however, the VCC requires 5V to operate. In the configuration shown above the 5V from VCC could damage the 3.3V GPIO pins of the MCU used to control the ESC.

My question is why has VCC been connected to the high-side switching logic pins? Or is this a mistake in the schematic? If this is not a mistake, any suggestions on how to best protect the 3.3V logic pins from the MCU from the 5V of VCC would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Looks like a classic 4-way crossover mistake in CAD. Email the manufacturer and ask for clarification/updated datasheet.

Comment: Will do! Thanks very much. I'll post any info I get back from the manufacturer here for anybody's future reference.

Comment: Logic input are 3.3/5 V compatible. So, no problems (?).

Comment: You are correct, the gate driver logic pins are 3.3/5V compatible, however, these logic pins are input pins that will be driven by an MCU output. If the MCU GPIO is only 3.3V compatible a 5V connection to VCC would cause damage to the MCU. It is also unclear from the datasheet why VCC is connected to the high-side switching logic pins.

Comment: Ok ... I did not see the "dot" across the lines HIN1,HIN2,HIN3 and Dbs ... There is no dot as pointed out by @Thijs

Answer (score 1):

[image: the same schematic but from the chinese datasheet]

The chinese datasheet has this schematic, so i'm pretty sure it's just a little mistake.